# Is it possible to find out whether a post got into the LQP review queue by an automated process or by manual flagging?

Tags: support, review, flags, low-quality-posts

When a post appears in the review queue, it is possible to find out whether it was picked by software or whether it has been flagged manually?

I recall seeing this message on some posts in the Low Quality Posts review queue:

> "This question/answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content."

Am I correct in thinking that this indicates posts that it was "auto-flagged"?

If you look at the review after it was finished (for example through review history) no message like that can be seen, only the actions taken by the reviewers. Is it possible to find out in the case of completed review whether a post has been chosen by some filter or manually flagged?

Answer (score 9):

> When a post appears in the review queue, it is possible to find out whether it was picked by software or whether it has been flagged manually?

♦ moderators can see in their flag queue whether a flag was raised by a user or automatically. Otherwise, it's not possible, unless you know details of the algorithm behind that software. From my experience with flags on Ask Different I can make a decent prediction about what gets auto-flagged and what not on other sites. Sometimes, it's pretty obvious; I remember reviewing a pretty good answer on English Language Learners of which I'm 100% sure somebody had revenge flagged it as Very Low Quality (or Not An Answer), otherwise it would never end up in the queue.

> > "This question/answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content."
>
> Am I correct in thinking that this indicates posts that it was "auto-flagged"?

No, that phrase is shown for *all* posts in the Low Quality Posts review queue, just like the following is always shown in the First Posts review queue:

> This is the **first question** asked by a new user. Help them learn to use the site by reviewing their post.

<sub>(well, for answers it's **first answer**, but otherwise it's the same)</sub>